# iOS, View width - out of bounds

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uistoryboard

I'm having an issue with storyboard (least bit surprised).

I have one ViewController which holds a container view along side various image views. Naturally, the image views selected determine what is displayed in the container view.

My issue is that when simulated on iPhone 6 plus, i have the container not meeting the edge of the window, thus creating a gap (See below - Left hand side).

[image]

My constraints are as seen below

[image]

As they appear in storyboard

[image]

**I'm lost as to how i am supposed to do this easily & correctly. Any suggestions?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete those two constraints and then add them again, this time unchecking "Constrain to margins".